# Specifying the output directory of XSLT splitting transformations in LXML

Tags: python, xml, xslt, lxml

I'm using Python's LXML library to run an XSLT against an XML document. This transformation uses the `exsl:document` functions to split my XML into smaller XML documents. Here's what my command looks like:

```
<exsl:document href="{//@LedgerNo}.xml" method="xml">
```

My script `script.py` and the transformation `transform.xsl` are in the same directory. When the transformation is run, the XML gets split successfully but the resultant files are created in the current working directory. Is there a way I could specify the output directory in LXML?

Thanks

Comment: Try to provide an absolute file path: `href="c:/temp/{//@LedgerNo}.xml"`

Comment: Maybe you can just change the working directory with `os.chdir`